# Cooking with barleywine

Tags: beer

Given that barleywine is a strong ale, is it suitable in recipes which call for ale, or does the extra alcohol and stronger flavor overwhelm the recipe?

I realize the answer will be "it depends" if varies by recipe; I am more interested in whether the answer is "Absolutely!" or "Absolutely not!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barleywines initially have a large amount of sugars in them before fermentation, and brewers balance that by adding a large amount of hops.  There is a large bitterness factor in a barleywine, which you may or may not notice, depending on your tastes and the individual brew.   If you try to reduce it like you might with a wine, the bitterness may quickly get overwhelming.

With that in mind, I see no reason why you couldn't use a barleywine in any recipe that would work with a strongly flavored beer.

Check out [The Home Brewed Chef](http://thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/The-Home-Brewed-Chef) for some great ideas for how to cook with beer.